# Запятые после слова "так" и перед словом "он"?

Tags: запятые

*Вася старался работать быстро, но при этом деятельность часто оказывалась недостаточно продуктивной. Так, в пробе на зрительные ассоциации он очень быстро изобразил различные предметы мебели.*

Нужно ли кусок "в пробе на зрительные ассоциации" выделять запятыми? А если убрать этот кусок, то нужна ли запятая после слова "так"? А если заменить слово "так" на слово "например"?

Answer (score 2):

1) В данном случае "так" является вводным словом. В этом случае  "так"   и  "так как" (с зависимыми словами) обособляются запятыми.
2) Предыдущий пункт моего ответа содержит два примера таких же "кусков". Это обстоятельсто, выраженное существительным с предлогом и может обособляться факультативно, на усмотрение автора.

Обстоятельства обособлятся факультативно:

1. Если обстоятельство выражено существительным с предлогом или без предлога; чаще всего обособляются обстоятельства, выраженные существительными с предлогами `благодаря, в зависимости от, вопреки, в связи с, вследствие, несмотря на, согласно, в соответствии с, ввиду, во избежание` и др.

`Но никто не догадался, что, благодаря именно этому обстоятельству, город был доведен до такого благосостояния, которому подобного не представляли летописи с самого его основания.
(М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. «История одного города»)`

Благодаря именно этому обстоятельству — обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное существительным с предлогом. Это обстоятельство могло бы и не обособляться.
*Примечание.* Оборот с предлогом "несмотря на" обычно обособляется.

2. Если это уточняющее обстоятельство места, времени, образа действия.

`Она ушла в глубь комнаты, к стеллажу, и, встав на одно колено, нагнулась над нижней полкой.
(В. Шефнер. «Сестра печали»)`

К стеллажу — обособленное уточняющее обстоятельство.

Answer (score 1):

По порядку:

1. Нужна ли запятая после слова “так“ в данном случае? Да, нужна, потому что оно выступает в качестве вводного слова, имеющего значение “связь мыслей в предложении“. Как Вы очень верно подумали, его можно сравнить со словом “например“, также относящемуся к вводным и к данному разряду по значению (запятая, как Вы поняли, также ставится), однако имеющему немного другой смысл.
2. “Кусок“, как Вы выразились, “в пробе на зрительные ассоциации“ может и обособляться, и не обособляться, что зависит от желания автора.